# Different error response body when on Azure

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an action which returns an error with JSON:

```
public JsonResult Error()
{
    this.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return this.Json(new { error = "some error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I test this locally, the body of the response is:

```
{"error":"some error"}
```

as expected but when published to Azure, the response body is

```
Bad Request
```

Why would there be a different behavior and how can I make Azure respond with the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

in the web.config file.

I found the solution through [this blog post](http://lloydholman.co.uk/iis-why-you-squashing-my-custom-error-responses/).

Answer (score 0):

Try telling IIS to not use it's error pages by using [`Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Resulting code would look like:

```
public JsonResult Error()
{
    this.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    this.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    return this.Json(new { error = "some error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```